# FL STUDIO: Add to favorites option in browser

Tags: daw, fl-studio

I'm searching for an option which would allow you to add your favorite samples, instruments etc. from the browser into some list "favorites". Is there something like that?

Answer (score 2):

This isnt available as far as I know But Ctrl+F takes you to the Browser Smart Find where you can key in for Instant access to all items in the browser